# Not able to see DataSources in OBIEE 11g for MapViewer

Tags: oracle11g, obiee, jmapviewer, oracle-map-viewer

I am trying to use mapviewer feature of OBIEE 11g. I have tried the following steps suggested in most of the blogs

- Downloaded the mvdemo database for sample spatial data
- Changed the configuration file in  to include the mapviewer url.
- Uncommented the DataSource section to give the credentials for the new database created for mvdemo
- Clicked Submit and Restart

Even after performing the above I was not able to see the DataSource that i configured in the Configuration xml.

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

you need to check these :

1. just to avoid mistyping, be sure that after you save mapViewerConfig.xml on mapviewer it show this popup

> File mapviewer.xml has been saved

not this

> The configuration file is not well formed

2. be sure that your user-previlage have an access to read/write this file

> ORACLE_HOME/config/fmwconfig/mapviewer/conf/mapViewerConfig.xml